# Implementing qsort in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, qsort

I'm trying to use qsort to sort a C array in descending order based on what [this website](http://blog.ablepear.com/2011/11/objective-c-tuesdays-sorting-arrays.html) is suggesting.

**Here is the relevant code:**

```
int x = 3;

- (IBAction)CaptureButton:(id)sender
{
  x++;
  if (x % 3 == 1) 
  {

  int areas[detectedBlobs.size()];

  for (int i = 0; i < detectedBlobs.size(); i++)
  {
      areas[i] = detectedBlobs[i].getWidth() * detectedBlobs[i].getHeight();
  }

  int compareInts(void const *item1, void const *item2)
  { // first error
      int const *int1 = item1;
      int const *int2 = item2;
      return (*int2 - *int1);
  }

  qsort(areas, detectedBlobs.size(), sizeof(int), compareInts); // second error
  }
}
```

**Here are the two errors I'm getting:**

**First error:**

> Function definition is not allowed here

**Second error:**

> Use of undeclared identifier 'compareInts'

If I cannot define the comparator (compareInts) function here, where do I have to define it? Also, how can I get the qsort function to recognize the comparator?

Comment: Put ` int compareInts(void const *item1, void const *item2) {int const *int1 = item1; int const *int2 = item2; return (*int2 - *int1);} before `- (IBAction)CaptureButton:(id)sender{` ?

Comment: instead of `int compareInts(void const *item1, void const *item2) { ... }`, try to use block inside the method's body, like `NSInteger (^comapreInts)(NSInteger, NSInteger) = ^NSInteger(NSInteger item1, NSInteger item2) { ... };` – or put those those outside of the method's body into separated methods, like `– (NSInteger)compareInt1:(NSInteger)item1 toInt2:(NSInteger)item2 { ... }` etc...

Comment: @holex - how do you pass a block or a method as a C function pointer?

Comment: @CRD, there is the block's reference for parameter; or the passing a selector as parameter is still a valid operand in Obj-C.

Comment: @holex - `qsort()` takes a C function pointer. You cannot pass it a block reference or Obj-C selector. See the accepted answer.

Comment: @CRD, indeed, you cannot pass an _ObjC_ method or an _ObjC_ block to an ANSI-C function; but I'm talking about using ObjC, rather than pure ANSI-C.

Comment: @holex - My first comment was meant to be a gentle hint you'd headed off in the wrong direction, it obviously missed the mark, apologies. The OP can't "try to use" a block or a method because `qsort()` is a library function which takes a C function pointer.

Comment: @CRD, I'm always gently and reasonable, you have read my words on the wrong way, but that is none of my business... what I said they should not use ANSI-C library function at the first place – that case is a typical XY problem unless it is a homework, because in such case the OP should have done their own investigation (from passive sources mostly) not asking the community to solve this homework for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objective-C does not allow function definitions inside methods. Move `compareInts` outside of the method, and make it `static` to hide from other translation units:

```
static int compareInts(const void* item1, const void* item2) {
    const int* int1 = (const int*)item1;
    const int* int2 = (const int*)item2;
    return (*int2 - *int1);
}

- (IBAction)CaptureButton:(id)sender {
    x++;
    if (x % 3 == 1) {
        int areas[detectedBlobs.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < detectedBlobs.size(); i++) {
            areas[i] = detectedBlobs[i].getWidth() * detectedBlobs[i].getHeight();
        }
        qsort(areas, detectedBlobs.size(), sizeof(int), compareInts);
    }
}
```

Comment: I just tried this, but I get this error on the const int* int1 and const int* int2 lines: Cannot initialize a variable of type 'const int *' with an lvalue of type 'const void *'.

Comment: @fi12 I guess Objective-C insists on a cast. Please see the edit.

Comment: It works beautifully! I'll accept your answer once the time limit expires.